# How to know if an AWS RDS instance is fully replicated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, replication, amazon-rds

I setup a replica in a different region for my RDS instance. It seems to be working except that the status is always "Replicating". How can I know that the instances are fully in sync? Eventually I would like to promote the replica to master but I want to make sure, first, that all data is on it.

Any idea how to check this?

Comment: There are multiple different types of RDS replication. Please let us know exactly what database you're using, and what replication type. eg read replica, standard multi-AZ, Multi-AZ deployments with two readable standbys ( https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/01/amazon-rds-multi-az-readable-standbys-rds-postgresql-inbound-replication/ ).

Comment: This is an RDS Postgres database, and the replica is a simple read read replica in a different region. I've just checked again and it still says "Replicating"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitor the Cloudwatch metric "ReplicaLag" ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-metrics.html)). If it's zero your replica is up to date.